# How to best arrange a C# Solution for Multiple projects

Tags: c#, project, solution

I'm looking at writing a C# solution that will contain a number of sub projects.  These projects will include a web service, a MVC website, POCO ?, a XML connector to connect to a remote data source and a data access layer to manage the calling of database stored procedures etc.

In addition, I will need a area for the business logic.

Are there any standards to following will arrange the project in terms of data access that I should look to follow ?  Any examples would be appreciated.

Comment: This question better fits Programmers SE:
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/40394/how-do-you-organize-your-projects

Comment: Could have a look into onion architecture - http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/ - there's an example MVC project on codeplex, as far as I recall. If nothing else, do consider its points about where e.g. database access goes. That said, the link @Fabian posted has some good discussion of various approaches.

Comment: Here is link to sample project from codeplex http://prodinner.codeplex.com/      , May be you cold have separate projects for web serivce and xml connector